# How can I select slug page from useRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

how can I add my all posts into this array. so I can use for conditional styling for the header component.

basically, it shows white header on other pages. and dark header on the homepage and 404 page. but I also want show dark header on all the projects pages. this didn't work.

**edit: found the solution.**

const darkBG = pages.includes(router.**asPath**);

this should be pathname instead of asPath

layout.tsx

```js
const DarkPages = [
"/projects/project/[id]",  <<<<< HERE
"/",
"/404,
];

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <MainHeader pages={DarkPages} />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

header.tsx

```js
const MainHeader = ({ pages }: any) => {

  const router = useRouter();
  const darkBG = pages.includes(router.asPath);

return (
    <header
      className={styles.nav}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: darkBG ? "#101010" : "#ffffff",
      }}
    >
</header>
```

Comment: have you tried "router.query.id" ?

Comment: you mean like this? didn't work. ["/projects/project/router.query.id", "/", "404];

Comment: no I thought you are trying to access the id in from the router. Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to get list of static paths to be generated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getStaticProps to get all the posts as prop to the component

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths which are pre-rendered based on posts
  const darkPages = posts.map((post) =>  post.id)

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { darkPages } }
}
```

In case you don't want to fetch the posts api in getStaticPaths and getStaticProps you can refer below vercel example to use file system cache to share responses across calls.

[Reuse api response in getStaticProps and getStaticPaths](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/solutions/reuse-responses)

Comment: thank you I think my questions wasn't right so I updated.

Comment: Did you mean getting the value of id inside component ?  If your file is /projects/project/[id].js  ```const router = useRouter();
  const slug = router.query.id;
  console.log(slug); //slug value```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `dark` header on all project pages, you have to do this.

```
const DarkPages = [
  "/",
  "/404,
  ];
  
    const router = useRouter();

    const projectPagesHeader = router.asPath.includes('/projects/project');
  
    return (
      <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
        <MainHeader pages={DarkPages} projectPagesHeader={projectPagesHeader} />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </MainContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

MainHeader.js

```
const MainHeader = ({ pages, projectPagesHeader }: any) => {

    const router = useRouter();
    const darkBG = pages.includes(router.asPath);
  
  return (
      <header
        className={styles.nav}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: darkBG || projectPagesHeader ? "#101010" : "#ffffff",
        }}
      >
  </header>
```

If you are passing the `params` in route, then your route path is not exact the `router.asPath` because these is always a different `id`, then you should use `includes` on `router.asPath`. I hope this works. thanks